# How to compute the residue of $(z^2+2z+1)\sin\left(\frac{1}{1+z}\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, residue-calculus, laurent-series

This was an example given in my notes but all it concluded was with something about an infinite principal part. How do we compute it? we have it equal to $ \left( z + 1 \right)^2 \cdot \sin \left( (z+1)^{-1}  \right) = \left( z + 1 \right)^2 \cdot \left[ (z+1)^{-1} + \cdots \right] $. That's all I could get. What now?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$z=-1$ is an essential singularity of the function. So we have $$(z^2+2z+1)\sin \frac{1}{1+z}=(z+1)^2\sin \frac{1}{1+z} $$ therefore $$(z+1)^2\sin \frac{1}{1+z}=(z+1)^2 \left(\frac{1}{1+z}-\frac{1}{3!(1+z)^3}+\frac{1}{5!(1+z)^5}-\cdots\right)$$ this shows that Res$[(z+1)^2\sin \frac{1}{1+z}, -1]=-\frac{1}{3!}$

Comment: Nice! I actually solved it that way but thought it was wrong for some reason. I had to compute sin(z+1/z) as well so I thought it was similar

Answer (score 2):

The function
$$
f(z)=(z+1)^{2}\sin(\frac{1}{z+1})
$$
has an essential singularity at $z=-1$, and the residue should be $-\frac{1}{6}$. This can be read from the Taylor expansion explicitly. Sorry for the nonsense wrote earlier.

Comment: @quid: updated. Sorry for writing without thinking.

Comment: No worries, I didn't even see what you wrote!:P

Comment: By the way, I think you made a typo that $\frac{1}{z+1}=(z+1)^{2}-...$. I suppose you were trying to use geometric series or something, but this does not hold.

Comment: Someone edited my stuff and changed what I wrote…I had factored (z^2+2z+1) into (z+1)^2 then used the fact that 1/(z+1) = (z+1)^-1 and used the sin expansion of that

Comment: @mrf: Of course you are right.